# Retrieve MongoDB binData and display as <img> src

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have stored an image to my mongoDB collection, and it looks something like:

```
{
  "photo" : {
    "image" : BinData(0,"/9j/4AAQS......"),
    "imageType": "image/jpeg"
  }
}
```

My router looks like:

```
app.get('/userImage', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.user.username;

  User.getProfilePicture(username, function(err, image) {
    if (err) {
      res.end('Error fetching photo');
    }
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', image.imageType);
    res.end(image.image.buffer, 'binary');
  });
});
```

The model looks like:

```
exports.getProfilePicture = function(username, callback) {
  var collection = db.get().collection('users');

  collection.find({ 'username': username }).toArray(function(err, users) {
    callback(err, users[0].photo);
  });
};
```

And the ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/userImage',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $image.src = data;
  }
});
```

On console.log in the route, I do:

```
console.log(image);
```

And I get:

```
{ image: 
   Binary {
     _bsontype: 'Binary',
     sub_type: 0,
     position: 42461,
     buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 43 00 05 03 04 04 04 03 05 04 04 04 05 05 05 06 07 0c 08 07 07 07 07 0f 0a 0b 09 ... > },
  imageType: 'image/jpeg' }
```

There is something wrong happening here, although I have followed instructions from other resources and stackoverflow questions.
The "data" in the success function is empty, although the "image.image" is not empty. Can anybody help me out here?

From this console.log, can anybody tell me how I can get the image to be shown through in the html?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is useful to u

this is my model

```
var ImageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
"photo" : {
"image" : Buffer,
    "imageType":{type:String}}});
var Image = mongoose.model('Error', ImageSchema);
module.exports = Image;
```

my data is stored like this

```
{
"photo" : {
"image" : BinData(0,"/9j/4AAQS......"),
"imageType": "image/jpeg"}}
```

get function

```
var Image = require(. / Image)
app.get('/image/:imageId', function(req, res) {
Image.findbyId(imageId, function(err, imagedata) {
    if (err)
        return err
    res.end(imagedata.photo.image);
})});
```

finally ajax call

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/image/123:',
success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $image.src = data
}});
```

and res.end() will send directly image data dont use res.send()

Comment: this way only am using . its working fin to me.. if u dont mind send your code , what  you have tried

Comment: I just changed res.send to res.end(image.image). Do I also have to remove the content type?

Comment: I am trying res.setHeader('Content-Type', image.imageType) and res.end(image.image.buffer, 'binary'). But it sends something I cannot recognise... Some weird characters.